# Multiple Layers Stacked Atop Each Other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build a section of a webpage (trough Bootstrap 3.0), and in this section I am trying to place three divs or layers atop each other.

So that it is stacked as follows: background "squares," footer, and foreground "squares" with images.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-1 col-md-offset-2" id="twitterBg">
        <div id="twitter"><a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png" class="img-responsive" id="twitterIcon" alt="Twitter Icon" /></a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-1 col-md-offset-2" id="dribbbleBg">
        <div id="dribbble"><img src="images/dribbble.png" class="img-responsive" id="dribbbleIcon" alt="Dribbble Icon" /></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-1 col-md-offset-2" id="facebookBg">
         <div id="facebook"><img src="images/facebook.png" class="img-responsive" id="facebookIcon" alt="Facebook Icon" /></div>
    </div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12" id="footer"></div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper2{
    height: 150px;
    padding: 0;
}

#twitterBg{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(26, 188, 156, .5);
    margin-top: 100px;
}

#dribbbleBg{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(26, 188, 156, .5);
    margin-top: 100px;
}

#facebookBg{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(26, 188, 156, .5);
    margin-top: 100px;
}

#twitter{
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 999;
}

#twitterIcon{
    padding: 20px;
}

#dribbble{
    width: 95px;
    height: 95px;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 999;
}

#dribbbleIcon{
    padding: 20px;
}

#facebook{
    width: 95px;
    height: 95px;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 999;
}

#facebookIcon{
    padding: 20px;
}

#footer{
    height: 240px;
    background-color: #1abc9c;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
```

Currently I cannot get them to stack. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you're using bootstrap 3 and you want a responsive site then you shouldn't be using pixel widths in your css

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to look at absolute positioning. I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve and why you'd want squares behind your footer. hopefully this helps you:http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: I don't think this is really an answer to the question

Comment: Well i don't really understand what the question is. And that's probably why no one has answered it yet.